# casperjs can't get full parameter-value which has '$'

Tags: parameters, casperjs

I use casperjs in Ubuntu like this,test.js content like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);
```

Then I run : `casperjs test.js --p1=aaaa --p2=bb$bb --p3=123$456`

I wish to get:

```
Casper CLI passed options:
{
  "casper-path": "/usr/casperjs",
  "cli": true,
  "p1": "aaaa",
  "p2": "bb$bb",
  "p3": "123$456"
}
```

but,actually:

```
Casper CLI passed options:
{
    "casper-path": "/usr/casperjs",
    "cli": true,
    "p1": "aaaa",
    "p2": "bb",
    "p3": 12356
}
```

I do not know why '$' disappear，and I need your help~
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting and escaping are important, as they influence the way Bash acts upon your input. There are three recognized types:

- **per-character escaping** using a backslash: \$stuff
- **weak quoting** with double-quotes: "stuff"
- **strong quoting** with single-quotes: 'stuff'

All three forms have the very same purpose: **They give you general control over parsing, expansion and expansion results.**

More info: [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)